# the centroid of the intersection of n disks/circles

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Given that n disks/circles share a common area, meaning that every two of them intersect one another, and we know their coordinates （x1,y1,r1), (x2,y2,r2), ..., (xn,yn,rn), where xi,yi,rn represent the x axis coordinate, the y axis coordinate, and the radius of the ith disks/circle, respectively, can you provide a method to  calculate the coordinate of the centroid of the intersection of these disks/circles?!

Comment: This is not particularly programming related, so you might try asking that at http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I looked at the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) on centroids and it seems to apply to overlapping shapes. So all of your circles overlap in such a way as to form a single shape, yes?

Comment: Well, there's a solution method, anyway.

Comment: True, @MvG, though if my answer is correct than it may be an algorithmic question.

Comment: @MvG, thank you for introducing to me a more appropriate place.

Comment: @Richard, right, all of these circles overlap or intersect one another.^^

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that all the circles overlap such that one can trace a path from any point in one of the circles to an arbitrary point in any other circle while traversing only points contained by circles. And, for generality, that the circles may be of different radii.

Per the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#By_geometric_decomposition) you can decompose this shape into separate geometric regions. That is, you can find an intermediate value for the centroid by considering each circle separately (i.e. pretending they do not overlap).

Unfortunately some of the circles overlap, so you will be counting regions of the figure twice. The figure below, taken from [this page](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/08/27/partition-an-area-with-circles-and-draw-each-regions-count-in-c.aspx), shows these regions of overlap.  You therefore must find the centroid of the circle-circle intersection and subtract this from your intermediate centroid (see the wiki page's description of geometric decomposition for further details).

[image]

Since you can determine which circles overlap just do these for each overlapping pair and then each region of space will be counted only once. Your problem then reduces to finding the centroid of a circle-circle intersection.

You can find this by using geometric decomposition to break each lens of intersection into [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centroids) with the height of the segment given via a method [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) and coupling the result with appropriate coordinate transformations to rotate and translate the centroid to a location relative the center of one of the circles.

Comment: You're talking about the centroid of the *union* of the circles, the OP was asking about the centroid of the *intersection* of the circles.  Of course, it is possible the OP got his terminology backwards, as the intersection is likely empty.

Comment: I feel foolish for not having observed this, @KeithRandall. Thanks for point this out! But I think I assumed that the OP was speaking of unions. If not, the above method has all the pieces needed to find the intersection.

Comment: @KeithRandall, as you said, I am really talking about the intersection of the circles.

Comment: @Richard, I feel so grateful to you for providing an inspirational answer in detail!

Comment: @YorkTsai, the equations on MathWorld for Circle-Circle Intersections and Circular Segments are not as good as I had hoped. I'm intrigued by this problem and am working on writing up a complete solution. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Richard, great, count me in.

Comment: @YorkTsai, I'm afraid the solution is not so simple as I had hoped. It ends up being very difficult to avoid subtracting the overlapping areas too many times. I'm still thinking about this, but I don't think there will be a "short 'n' sweet" algorithm for determining an analytic solution.

Comment: @Richard, there is a solution posted in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221881/the-intersection-of-n-disks-circles/225089#225089). But he just wrote a skeleton and I still need to implement it with programming skills.

Comment: @Richard, by the way, Rahul Narain told me that he drew the graph with a open source tool Inkscape. I guess I can get some tips from the souce code of the Inkscape. But reading the source code is not an easy thing. If you are so interested in the problem, this route may inspire you.