# Intersection of 4 circles

Tags: c#, math

Im trying to find the intersection area of 4 circles. Is there any way how to calculate it? I need it such that i can find the minimum point in the area that satisfies the intersection of the four circles.

Comment: What should happen / be returned in the case where the four circles doesn't intersect at the same point? Even with just 3 circles you might not have one common point where all 3 circles intersect.

Comment: belongs in math.stackexchange if there is one :D

Comment: math.se.com is for research level mathematics, I don't think this qualifies, but I would agree that SO might not be the best place either.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen in my case of application there will always be an intersection of 4 circles, i just need to know a hint or idea of an approach how i will compute the intersection.

Comment: Possible solution here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016550/the-centroid-of-the-intersection-of-n-disks-circles

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if there is no intersection of four circles it cant be good but in my case there will always be an intersection

Comment: Do you want a point that is ON all 4 circles, or an area that's WITHIN all 4 circles?

Comment: @HansKesting http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math4c/randprob/areaprob/fourcircles_files/image002.gif as u can see this is the intersecting area of four circles is that area therefore all points contained in the four circles intersection would be found in all the circles. Therefore within the area of the four circes

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen no no no! [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net) is for research-level mathematics; [math.se] is for *any* mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

I woudl define a GraphicPath for each cirlce, and generate the Region of intersection successively.